# Copy over values to new column with formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got the following `DataFrame`:

```
  geo col1  col2
0  CA    A     1
1  CA    A     2
2  CA    B     1
3  CA    B     2
4  CA    B     1
5  CA    C     1
6  CA    C     2
```

My goal is to create a new `column` that copies the value from `col2` if `col2 == 1` and copy the value from `col1` if `col2 == 2`.

The geo column is included in the image because eventually I'd like to create an if statement that does the above slightly differently for 15-20 states in the US.

The end goal would look like this:

```
  geo col1  col2 col3
0  CA    A     1    1
1  CA    A     2    A
2  CA    B     1    1
3  CA    B     2    B
4  CA    B     1    1
5  CA    C     1    1
6  CA    C     2    C
```

Comment: (Aside: it's more convenient for people trying to help if you post *text*, not images.  Text can be easily copy-pasted, whereas if someone wants to test their code on your example data they'd have to type it in element by element.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your conditional copy statements into a function to make the various cases more manageable [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def copy_function(row):
    if row['col2']==1:
        return row['col2'] 
    else: 
        return row['col1']
df['col3'] = df.apply(copy_function, axis=1)
```

Comment: this works but when I start adding in all the exception cases it gets pretty long/unruly. How would I translate that to a standalone function?

Comment: Updated. You can expand the `if/elif/else` statements as you wish. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps.

```
for row in rows:
    row['col3'] = row['col1'] if row['col2'] == 2 else row['col2']
```

Comment: Do I then save that as a function and apply it to the dataframe or could I just run that on it's own and have it append the column to the original df?

Comment: it will work both ways. if you choose to use a function just make sure to pass the data as a valid iterable for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['col3'] = [c2 if c2 == 1 else (c1 if c2 == 2 else None) 
              for c1, c2 in zip(df.col1, df.col2)]

>>> df
  geo col1  col2 col3
0  CA    A     1    1
1  CA    A     2    A
2  CA    B     1    1
3  CA    B     2    B
4  CA    B     1    1
5  CA    C     1    1
6  CA    C     2    C
```

Given your exception cases stated in your comments, you can also use `iterrows`:

```
df['col3'] = None
for n, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.col2 == 1:
        df.ix[n, 'col3'] = row.col2
    elif row.col2 == 2:
        df.ix[n, 'col3'] = row.col1
    # Other cases.
```